# listview with balloons in android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a listview with balloons. Its like a threaded chat list.
[image]

I am using thread.9.png (9 patch image) image for balloons. but you can see in the above screen shot that balloons are taking screen width even content is smaller.

I want to resize balloon's width on the basis of content.

bellow is the code of list view row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingLeft="2dp"
  android:background="@drawable/thread">


    <TextView 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:id="@+id/messageFrom" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dip"></TextView>


    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/messageTitle" 
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:layout_gravity="right" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"></TextView>
     <TextView 
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" 
        android:id="@+id/messageDay" 
        android:text="TextView" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If there is any sample for threaded list view, it will also very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 9patch image won't shrink (will only stretch), so if the thread.9.png's width is greater than the content size, it'll use the images width.

Comment: so any suggestion of minimum width??

Answer (score 1):

You have to design your balloon background image with the minimum width you want

Answer (score 1):

try with the sub linearlayout, as the list row fill the main layout even you set the width as wrap_content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_bg1" android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView android:text="text view one" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffff0000" android:textSize="20dp" android:id="@+id/text1"/>
        <TextView android:text="text view two" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#ffff0000" android:textSize="20dp" android:id="@+id/text2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```